# processing collision test return false at the beginning

Tags: processing, collision-detection

I am doing the collision test for the programme, and I tried to insert the test into `draw()` and I'm expecting it to display "GameOver" and no further events will result any change.

```java
float x;
float y;
float w;
float h;

float xPed;
float yPed;
float yPedc;

float objectX;
float objectY;
float objectWidth;
float objectHeight;

float triangleWidth;
float triangleHeight;

float dia;
int speed = 2;

boolean gameOver;

int N_LANES = 1;

void setup() {

    size(1200, 400);
    background(255);

    x = width / 60;
    y = height / 40;
    w = width / 80;

    xPed = width / 2;

    triangleWidth = height / 4;

    triangleHeight = 2.5 * w;

    yPed = height - 3 * w;

    yPedc = 2.5 * w / 2;

    dia = w / 2;
    h = w / 2;

    objectX = x + 2 * w;

    objectY = y + 5 * h;

    objectWidth = 4 * w;

    objectHeight = 10 * h;

    gameOver = false;
}

void  draw() {

    //reset background
    background(255);
    line(0, height/4, width, height/4);
    
    vehicle();
    pedestrian();

    // collision detect
    if (gameOver == true) {

        textSize(100);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        text("Game Over", width / 3, height / 2);

    }

}

void vehicle() {

    //moving vehicle
    x += speed;

    // reset vehicle
    noFill();

    if (x > width) {

        x = 0;

    } else if (x < 0) {
        x = width;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N_LANES; i++) {
        //head of vehicle
        fill(0, 194, 0, 50);
        rect(x, y, w, h);
        rect(x + 3 * w, y, w, h);
        rect(x, y + h, 4 * w, 4 *h);

        //eyes of vehicle
        fill(0);
        rect(x + w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);
        rect(x + 3 * w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);

        //body of vehicle
        fill(0, 240, 0, 80);
        rect(x + 1.5 * w, 6.3 * h, 1.5 * w, 3 *h );
        //left arm
        line(x + 1.5 *w, 6.3 * h, x + 0.5 * w, 7.3 * h);
        //right arm
        line(x + 3 * w, 6.3 * h, x + 4 * w, 7.3 * h);
        //left leg 
        line(x + 1.5 * w, 9.3 * h, x + w, 11.3 * h);
        //right leg
        line(x + 3 * w, 9.3 * h, x + 3.5 * w, 11.3 * h);

    }

}

// draw pedestrian
void pedestrian() {

    fill(255, 140, 0, 70);

    //body of pedestrian

    triangle(xPed, yPed, xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w, xPed + triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w);

    fill(0);

    circle(xPed + triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

    circle(xPed - triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

    fill(255, 165, 0);

    ellipse(xPed, yPed + w, 1.5 * dia, 3 * dia);
    
}

// arrow key moving
void keyPressed() {
    if (gameOver != true) {

        if (key == CODED) {

            if (keyCode == UP) {
                yPed -= height / 4;

                if (yPed <= 0) {
                    yPed = height - 3 * w;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode == DOWN) {
                yPed += height / 4;

                if (yPed > height) {
                    yPed = height - 3 * w;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode==LEFT) {
                xPed -= height / 4;
                if (xPed < 0 + triangleWidth / 2) {
                    xPed = width / 2;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
                xPed += height / 4;

                if (xPed > width - triangleWidth / 2) {
                    xPed = width / 2;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}

boolean gameOver() {
    // optional visualise collision objects
    rect(objectX, objectY, objectWidth, objectHeight);
    rect(xPed, yPed, triangleWidth, triangleHeight);
    // x axis
    float distX = abs( (objectX + objectWidth / 2) - (xPed + triangleWidth / 2) );
    // y axis
    float distY = abs( (objectY + objectHeight / 2) - (yPedc + triangleHeight / 2) );
    // half combined x distance
    float combinedHalfWidth = ( (objectWidth / 2) + (triangleWidth / 2) );
    // half combined y distance
    float combinedHalfHeight = ( (objectHeight / 2) + (triangleHeight / 2) );
    
    // check collision
    if (distX < combinedHalfWidth) {
        if (distY < combinedHalfHeight) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;

}
```

I tried to insert the `gameOver` boolean into draw and it returns the same value everytime.
Just wondering what the logical problem or the coding problem is.

Comment: Please format your code properly. See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rabbid76 mentions, you should format the code correctly first.

Let's assume the code been copied from a pdf with code snippets and that's how formatting got messed up.

The code still has a few glaring bugs:

- confusingly you're using both a boolean variable `gameOver` and a boolean function `gameOver()` and the variable isn't always updated. (In fact `gameOver` is only set once in `setup()` and `gameOver()` which actually does the collision detection is **never** called). I recommend either update the boolean variable, or simpler yet, just call `gameOver()` to compute the collision as needed. This is one of the reasons your code won't behave as you expect.
- You're checking collisions between two objects: the vehicle and the pedestrian. However, there are 3 sets of coordinates: `x, y, xPed, objectX, objectY`. When rendering in draw, the vehicle uses `x,y`, however, when checking for collisions, `gameOver()` uses `objectX, objectY` (which don't match and aren't updated).  This is the other reason you're collisions don't behave as expected.
- aside from the question you've asked, `N_LANES` is used in a for loop, but never declared. Even if I declare it, the for loop uses the exact same `x,y` coordinates, making the for loop redundant.

Here's a formatted version of your code with extra bounding boxes highlighting what the collision function is checking against (and commenting a few unused variables):

```java
float x;
float y;
float w;
float h;

float xPed;
float yPed;
//float yPedc;

float objectX;
float objectY;
float objectWidth;
float objectHeight;

float triangleWidth;
float triangleHeight;

float dia;
int speed = 2;

//boolean gameOver;

int N_LANES = 1;

void setup() {

    size(1200, 400);
    background(255);

    x = width / 60;
    y = height / 40;
    w = width / 80;

    xPed = width / 2;

    triangleWidth = height / 4;

    triangleHeight = 2.5 * w;

    yPed = height - 3 * w;

    //yPedc = 2.5 * w / 2;

    dia = w / 2;
    h = w / 2;

    objectX = x + 2 * w;

    objectY = y + 5 * h;

    objectWidth = 4 * w;

    objectHeight = 10 * h;

    //gameOver = false;
}

void  draw() {

    //reset background
    background(255);
    line(0, height/4, width, height/4);
    
    vehicle();
    pedestrian();

    // collision detect
    if (gameOver() == true) {

        textSize(100);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        text("Game Over", width / 3, height / 2);

    }

}

void vehicle() {

    //moving vehicle
    x += speed;

    // reset vehicle
    noFill();

    if (x > width) {

        x = 0;

    } else if (x < 0) {
        x = width;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N_LANES; i++) {
        //head of vehicle
        fill(0, 194, 0, 50);
        rect(x, y, w, h);
        rect(x + 3 * w, y, w, h);
        rect(x, y + h, 4 * w, 4 *h);

        //eyes of vehicle
        fill(0);
        rect(x + w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);
        rect(x + 3 * w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);

        //body of vehicle
        fill(0, 240, 0, 80);
        rect(x + 1.5 * w, 6.3 * h, 1.5 * w, 3 *h );
        //left arm
        line(x + 1.5 *w, 6.3 * h, x + 0.5 * w, 7.3 * h);
        //right arm
        line(x + 3 * w, 6.3 * h, x + 4 * w, 7.3 * h);
        //left leg 
        line(x + 1.5 * w, 9.3 * h, x + w, 11.3 * h);
        //right leg
        line(x + 3 * w, 9.3 * h, x + 3.5 * w, 11.3 * h);

    }

}

// draw pedestrian
void pedestrian() {

    fill(255, 140, 0, 70);

    //body of pedestrian

    triangle(xPed, yPed, xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w, xPed + triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w);

    fill(0);

    circle(xPed + triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

    circle(xPed - triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

    fill(255, 165, 0);

    ellipse(xPed, yPed + w, 1.5 * dia, 3 * dia);
    
    // visualise bounding box
    //fill(255, 140, 0, 70);
    //rect(xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed, triangleWidth, triangleHeight);
}

// arrow key moving
void keyPressed() {
    if (gameOver() != true) {

        if (key == CODED) {

            if (keyCode == UP) {
                yPed -= height / 4;

                if (yPed <= 0) {
                    yPed = height - 3 * w;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode == DOWN) {
                yPed += height / 4;

                if (yPed > height) {
                    yPed = height - 3 * w;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode==LEFT) {
                xPed -= height / 4;
                if (xPed < 0 + triangleWidth / 2) {
                    xPed = width / 2;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
                xPed += height / 4;

                if (xPed > width - triangleWidth / 2) {
                    xPed = width / 2;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}

boolean gameOver() {
    // optional visualise collision objects
    rect(objectX, objectY, objectWidth, objectHeight);
    rect(xPed, yPed, triangleWidth, triangleHeight);
    // x axis
    float distX = abs( (objectX + objectWidth / 2) - (xPed + triangleWidth / 2) );
    // y axis
    float distY = abs( (objectY + objectHeight / 2) - (yPed + triangleHeight / 2) );
    // half combined x distance
    float combinedHalfWidth = ( (objectWidth / 2) + (triangleWidth / 2) );
    // half combined y distance
    float combinedHalfHeight = ( (objectHeight / 2) + (triangleHeight / 2) );
    
    // check collision
    if (distX < combinedHalfWidth) {
        if (distY < combinedHalfHeight) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;

}
```

Here's a version of the code with a few of the 3 notes above applied, somewhat resolving the collision and gameOver state issue:

```java
float x;
float y;
float w;
float h;

float xPed;
float yPed;

float objectWidth;
float objectHeight;

float triangleWidth;
float triangleHeight;

float dia;
int speed = 2;

void setup() {

    size(1200, 400);
    background(255);

    x = width / 60;
    y = height / 40;
    w = width / 80;

    xPed = width / 2;

    triangleWidth = height / 4;

    triangleHeight = 2.5 * w;

    yPed = height - 3 * w;

    dia = w / 2;
    h = w / 2;

    objectWidth = 4 * w;

    objectHeight = 10 * h;
}

void  draw() {

    //reset background
    background(255);
    line(0, height/4, width, height/4);
    
    vehicle();
    pedestrian();

    // collision detect
    if (gameOver()) {

        textSize(100);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        text("Game Over", width / 3, height / 2);

    }

}

void vehicle() {

    //moving vehicle
    x += speed;

    // reset vehicle
    noFill();

    if (x > width) {

        x = 0;

    } else if (x < 0) {
        x = width;
    }
    
    //head of vehicle
    fill(0, 194, 0, 50);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
    rect(x + 3 * w, y, w, h);
    rect(x, y + h, 4 * w, 4 *h);

    //eyes of vehicle
    fill(0);
    rect(x + w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);
    rect(x + 3 * w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);

    //body of vehicle
    fill(0, 240, 0, 80);
    rect(x + 1.5 * w, 6.3 * h, 1.5 * w, 3 *h );
    //left arm
    line(x + 1.5 *w, 6.3 * h, x + 0.5 * w, 7.3 * h);
    //right arm
    line(x + 3 * w, 6.3 * h, x + 4 * w, 7.3 * h);
    //left leg 
    line(x + 1.5 * w, 9.3 * h, x + w, 11.3 * h);
    //right leg
    line(x + 3 * w, 9.3 * h, x + 3.5 * w, 11.3 * h);
}

// draw pedestrian
void pedestrian() {

    fill(255, 140, 0, 70);

    //body of pedestrian
    triangle(xPed, yPed, xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w, xPed + triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w);

    fill(0);

    circle(xPed + triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

    circle(xPed - triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

    fill(255, 165, 0);

    ellipse(xPed, yPed + w, 1.5 * dia, 3 * dia);
    
    // visualise bounding box
    //fill(255, 140, 0, 70);
    //rect(xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed, triangleWidth, triangleHeight);
}

// arrow key moving
void keyPressed() {
    if (!gameOver()) {

        if (key == CODED) {

            if (keyCode == UP) {
                yPed -= height / 4;

                if (yPed <= 0) {
                    yPed = height - 3 * w;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode == DOWN) {
                yPed += height / 4;

                if (yPed > height) {
                    yPed = height - 3 * w;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode==LEFT) {
                xPed -= height / 4;
                if (xPed < 0 + triangleWidth / 2) {
                    xPed = width / 2;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
                xPed += height / 4;

                if (xPed > width - triangleWidth / 2) {
                    xPed = width / 2;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}

boolean gameOver() {
    // optional visualise collision objects
    rect(x, y, objectWidth, objectHeight);
    rect(xPed, yPed, triangleWidth, triangleHeight);
    // x axis
    float distX = abs( (x + objectWidth / 2) - (xPed + triangleWidth / 2) );
    // y axis
    float distY = abs( (y + objectHeight / 2) - (yPed + triangleHeight / 2) );
    // half combined x distance
    float combinedHalfWidth = ( (objectWidth / 2) + (triangleWidth / 2) );
    // half combined y distance
    float combinedHalfHeight = ( (objectHeight / 2) + (triangleHeight / 2) );
    
    // check collision
    if (distX < combinedHalfWidth) {
        if (distY < combinedHalfHeight) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;

}
```

Notice that the triangle bounding box needs to be moved to the left by half the triangle width ideally.

I'd also like to point you to `java.awt.Rectangle` which has an [`intersects()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects(java.awt.Rectangle)) that could be useful:

```java
import java.awt.Rectangle;

float x;
float y;
float w;
float h;

float xPed;
float yPed;

float objectWidth;
float objectHeight;

float triangleWidth;
float triangleHeight;

float dia;
int speed = 2;

Rectangle vehicleBoundingBox;
Rectangle pedestrianBoundingBox;

void setup() {

    size(1200, 400);
    background(255);

    x = width / 60;
    y = height / 40;
    w = width / 80;

    xPed = width / 2;

    triangleWidth = height / 4;

    triangleHeight = 2.5 * w;

    yPed = height - 3 * w;

    dia = w / 2;
    h = w / 2;

    objectWidth = 4 * w;

    objectHeight = 10 * h;
    
    vehicleBoundingBox = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)objectWidth, (int)objectHeight);
    pedestrianBoundingBox = new Rectangle((int)xPed, (int)yPed, (int)triangleWidth, (int)triangleHeight);
}

void  draw() {

    //reset background
    background(255);
    line(0, height/4, width, height/4);
    
    vehicle();
    pedestrian();

    // collision detect
    if (gameOver()) {

        textSize(100);
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        text("Game Over", width / 3, height / 2);

    }

}

void vehicle() {

    //moving vehicle
    x += speed;

    // reset vehicle
    noFill();

    if (x > width) {

        x = 0;

    } else if (x < 0) {
        x = width;
    }
    
    //head of vehicle
    fill(0, 194, 0, 50);
    rect(x, y, w, h);
    rect(x + 3 * w, y, w, h);
    rect(x, y + h, 4 * w, 4 *h);

    //eyes of vehicle
    fill(0);
    rect(x + w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);
    rect(x + 3 * w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);

    //body of vehicle
    fill(0, 240, 0, 80);
    rect(x + 1.5 * w, 6.3 * h, 1.5 * w, 3 *h );
    //left arm
    line(x + 1.5 *w, 6.3 * h, x + 0.5 * w, 7.3 * h);
    //right arm
    line(x + 3 * w, 6.3 * h, x + 4 * w, 7.3 * h);
    //left leg 
    line(x + 1.5 * w, 9.3 * h, x + w, 11.3 * h);
    //right leg
    line(x + 3 * w, 9.3 * h, x + 3.5 * w, 11.3 * h);
}

// draw pedestrian
void pedestrian() {

    fill(255, 140, 0, 70);

    //body of pedestrian
    triangle(xPed, yPed, xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w, xPed + triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w);

    fill(0);

    circle(xPed + triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

    circle(xPed - triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

    fill(255, 165, 0);

    ellipse(xPed, yPed + w, 1.5 * dia, 3 * dia);
}

// arrow key moving
void keyPressed() {
    if (!gameOver()) {

        if (key == CODED) {

            if (keyCode == UP) {
                yPed -= height / 4;

                if (yPed <= 0) {
                    yPed = height - 3 * w;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode == DOWN) {
                yPed += height / 4;

                if (yPed > height) {
                    yPed = height - 3 * w;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode==LEFT) {
                xPed -= height / 4;
                if (xPed < 0 + triangleWidth / 2) {
                    xPed = width / 2;
                }
            }

            if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
                xPed += height / 4;

                if (xPed > width - triangleWidth / 2) {
                    xPed = width / 2;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}

boolean gameOver(){
  // update bounding box positions
  vehicleBoundingBox.x = (int)x;
  vehicleBoundingBox.y = (int)y;
  
  pedestrianBoundingBox.x = (int)(xPed - triangleWidth / 2);
  pedestrianBoundingBox.y = (int)yPed;
  //optional: visualise boxes
  fill(255, 140, 0, 70);
  rect(pedestrianBoundingBox.x, pedestrianBoundingBox.y, pedestrianBoundingBox.width, pedestrianBoundingBox.height);
  rect(vehicleBoundingBox.x, vehicleBoundingBox.y, vehicleBoundingBox.width, vehicleBoundingBox.height);
  
  return vehicleBoundingBox.intersects(pedestrianBoundingBox);
}

//boolean gameOver() {
//    // optional visualise collision objects
//    rect(x, y, objectWidth, objectHeight);
//    rect(xPed, yPed, triangleWidth, triangleHeight);
//    // x axis
//    float distX = abs( (x + objectWidth / 2) - (xPed + triangleWidth / 2) );
//    // y axis
//    float distY = abs( (y + objectHeight / 2) - (yPed + triangleHeight / 2) );
//    // half combined x distance
//    float combinedHalfWidth = ( (objectWidth / 2) + (triangleWidth / 2) );
//    // half combined y distance
//    float combinedHalfHeight = ( (objectHeight / 2) + (triangleHeight / 2) );
    
//    // check collision
//    if (distX < combinedHalfWidth) {
//        if (distY < combinedHalfHeight) {
//            return true;
//        }
//    }
    
//    return false;

//}

void circle(float x, float y, float dia){
  ellipse(x, y, dia, dia);
}
```

Bare in mind, if this is an assignment/homework, you might not be allowed to use java.awt.Rectangle. Speaking of which, if this is an assignment you should mention that in the question.

**Update**

Here's an updated version better handling the game over state.

```java
float x;
float y;
float w;
float h;

float xPed;
float yPed;

float objectWidth;
float objectHeight;

float triangleWidth;
float triangleHeight;

float dia;
int speed = 2;
// defaults to false
boolean isGameOver;

void setup() {

  size(1200, 400);
  background(255);

  x = width / 60;
  y = height / 40;
  w = width / 80;

  xPed = width / 2;

  triangleWidth = height / 4;

  triangleHeight = 2.5 * w;

  yPed = height - 3 * w;

  dia = w / 2;
  h = w / 2;

  objectWidth = 4 * w;

  objectHeight = 10 * h;
}

void  draw() {
  //reset background
  background(255);
  line(0, height/4, width, height/4);

  
  if (isGameOver) {
    textSize(100);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    text("Game Over", width / 3, height / 2);
  }else{
    // check colloisions only in game state and update game over state
    isGameOver = checkCollisions();
    vehicle();
    pedestrian();
  }
  
}

void vehicle() {

  //moving vehicle
  x += speed;

  // reset vehicle
  noFill();

  if (x > width) {

    x = 0;
  } else if (x < 0) {
    x = width;
  }

  //head of vehicle
  fill(0, 194, 0, 50);
  rect(x, y, w, h);
  rect(x + 3 * w, y, w, h);
  rect(x, y + h, 4 * w, 4 *h);

  //eyes of vehicle
  fill(0);
  rect(x + w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);
  rect(x + 3 * w, 3 * y, w * 0.85, h);

  //body of vehicle
  fill(0, 240, 0, 80);
  rect(x + 1.5 * w, 6.3 * h, 1.5 * w, 3 *h );
  //left arm
  line(x + 1.5 *w, 6.3 * h, x + 0.5 * w, 7.3 * h);
  //right arm
  line(x + 3 * w, 6.3 * h, x + 4 * w, 7.3 * h);
  //left leg 
  line(x + 1.5 * w, 9.3 * h, x + w, 11.3 * h);
  //right leg
  line(x + 3 * w, 9.3 * h, x + 3.5 * w, 11.3 * h);
}

// draw pedestrian
void pedestrian() {

  fill(255, 140, 0, 70);

  //body of pedestrian
  triangle(xPed, yPed, xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w, xPed + triangleWidth / 2, yPed + 2.5 * w);

  fill(0);

  circle(xPed + triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

  circle(xPed - triangleWidth / 4, yPed, dia);

  fill(255, 165, 0);

  ellipse(xPed, yPed + w, 1.5 * dia, 3 * dia);

  // visualise bounding box
  //fill(255, 140, 0, 70);
  //rect(xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed, triangleWidth, triangleHeight);
}

// arrow key moving
void keyPressed() {
  if (isGameOver){
    // exit game over
    isGameOver = false;
    // lazy way to restart the game
    // normally you'd write & call a reset() function to reset player/vehicle positions, avodiing instant gameOver
    setup();
  } else {

    if (key == CODED) {

      if (keyCode == UP) {
        yPed -= height / 4;

        if (yPed <= 0) {
          yPed = height - 3 * w;
        }
      }

      if (keyCode == DOWN) {
        yPed += height / 4;

        if (yPed > height) {
          yPed = height - 3 * w;
        }
      }

      if (keyCode==LEFT) {
        xPed -= height / 4;
        if (xPed < 0 + triangleWidth / 2) {
          xPed = width / 2;
        }
      }

      if (keyCode==RIGHT) {
        xPed += height / 4;

        if (xPed > width - triangleWidth / 2) {
          xPed = width / 2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

boolean checkCollisions() {
  // optional visualise collision objects
  fill(255, 140, 0, 70);
  rect(x, y, objectWidth, objectHeight);
  rect(xPed - triangleWidth / 2, yPed, triangleWidth, triangleHeight);
  // x axis
  float distX = abs( (x + objectWidth / 2) - xPed );
  // y axis
  float distY = abs( (y + objectHeight / 2) - (yPed + triangleHeight / 2) );
  // half combined x distance
  float combinedHalfWidth = ( (objectWidth / 2) + (triangleWidth / 2) );
  // half combined y distance
  float combinedHalfHeight = ( (objectHeight / 2) + (triangleHeight / 2) );

  // check collision
  if (distX < combinedHalfWidth) {
    if (distY < combinedHalfHeight) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

The main changes are:

- reintroduced `gameOver` boolean as `isGameOver` which is used to change between the two states
- renamed `gameOver()` to `checkCollisions()` to avoid confusion.

In this case, with just two states, a boolean will do.
It's important to also reset game variables when changing state (e.g. reset player/vehicle positions, etc.)
In case your game may require more states you can use an integer and constants. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846379/interactive-video-player-in-processing/33892849#33892849) has a demo code snippet.
If multiple states are required OOP was introduced, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081842/processing-how-to-fix-timer-display-and-how-to-display-time-score-at-end-of-gam/64106780#64106780) also has demo code.

Comment: Thanks for the epic answers. Sorry I’m a  rookie. And it’s a mess declaring the variables. 
Other question is how do I achieve this if collision detected or gameOver is true verified there is no further events result any change. I tried to put the if gameOver not true and then the drawing else the showing GameOver. But somehow it either not detecting at all or showing game over at beginning

Comment: The reason being I draw the character using top left x,y. But I realised I need Center point for collision detection so I declared another variable to make it up .  
I felt so silly when I look back the code I wrote. 
Can I use check collision by checking whether the side overlaying or dist() between Center point  are they both going to achieve the same ?

Comment: No need to be sorry, you're learning. No need to feel silly either: you can have a-ha moments which should help you progress, but feelings of guilt won't help you much. I see coding as an iterative process of thinking/testing/failing/tweaking/fixing. Failing is part of the process and it's where the lessons come from: you learn more this way than if things would've just worked but you wouldn't quite understand why. Back to your questions, I recommend asking separate questions specifically about these two issues: 1. how to manage game states. 2. how to do perform collision detection using dist.

Comment: Feel free to link to these questions here. I'm glad the answer was helpful: feel free to vote it up if that was the case. If it was the solution to your collision/gameOver problem mark it as such with the green check mark. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @ZIHENGWANG I've updated the answer above to handle the game over state change.

Comment: this is awesome, thank you so much. I think the I understand the logic but struggle with the implantation